# Get records of call that are made by specific Number in Plivo API

Tags: api, plivo

When I make a call through PLIVO API and want to get the list of the calls made. I send the request to the API as :

```
GET https://api.plivo.com/v1/Account/{auth_id}/Call/
```

I am using multiple numbers to make a call through single PLIVO API KEY. So,Is there any method by which I can get the list of calls that are made from a specific number.
Like if I send the request to the API along with the CALL FROM number so as to fetch the call List of only those calls that are made from the given number. Will something like this work :

> `https://api.plivo.com/v1/Account/{auth_id}/Call/call_from?=9188XXXXXXXX`

Kindly suggest a way to achieve the list of the calls made from a specific number using the PLIVO API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be simply achieved by :

```
$post_url = "https://api.plivo.com/v1/Account/MY-UNIQUE-AUTH-ID/Call/?from_number=".$numberOfCaller."&to_number=".$numberToBeCalled;
```

The Caller's Number is dynamic and the Call-to number is also dynamic in this approach.

Answer (score 0):

I think call_from is wrong, try From so:

```
?From=
```

Comment: I checked this myself and it is actually :
*?from_number=*